# why my resque cannot queue job in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I have a worker in which I write a lot of "puts .." to show the log and call some stored procedures to run sql. And the argument is an array, sometimes is long, but shorter than 10.  These are all its difference from other workers...

However, I can run the job successfully in my localhost and staging server. But when I deploy the production server. It doesn't queue the job in the queue, nor does it shows it fails. It seems it is not creating job at all. But other resque job can run successfully.

Do I have any configuration problem ...? or other solutions?

Comment: So only a single specific resque job is not working? Could you attach the code related to it.